# Apply transitions to many selections

Tags: d3.js

I would like to apply a transition to a whole group instead of doing it on all its elements line by line. For example :

```
myGroup = svg.append('g')
myText = myGroup.append('text').text('yo')
myRect = myGroup.append('rect')
```

I would like to transition the opacity to 0 without doing it like that :

```
myRect.transition().duration(1000).attr('opacity', 0)
myText.transition().duration(1000).attr('opacity', 0)
```

I tried `myGroup.transition().duration(1000).attr('opacity', 0)` but it didn't worked.

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to use a common Class on the elements you want to transition together, for example:

```
myGroup = svg.append('g')
myText = myGroup.append('text').text('yo').attr('class', 'transition')
myRect = myGroup.append('rect').attr('class', 'transition')

d3.selectAll('.transition').transition().duration(1000).attr('opacity', 0)
```